# How would you go about dereference a vector iterator

Tags: c++, vector

I'm currently learning C++ and ran into a little problem. The code below prints the address on the vector, but how do I let it spill the contents behind the address?

```
std::vector<BasePayroll*> emps;
emps.push_back(&Jane);

for (std::vector<BasePayroll*>::iterator it = emps.begin(); it != emps.end(); it++ ) {
    std::cout << *it;
}
```

Comment: The same way you get to "spill the contents behind a pointer". Do you know how to do that?

Comment: `*it` is a pointer to a `BasePayroll`.    If you want to access the data that pointer points at, dereference `*it`.    For example, if `BasePayroll` has a public member named `foo`, it can be accessed as `(*it)->foo` or (equivalently) `(**it).foo`.   If that member is printable (e.g. it is an `int`) then `std::cout << (*it)->foo` will print it.

Comment: You have a vector of `BasePayroll*` pointers. When you dereference an `iterator` to this vector, you get a `BasePayroll*` pointer. So of course `std::cout` is going to print out a memory address, because that is what you are giving it. What do you expect the output to be instead? The content of the `BasePayroll` object being pointed at? If so, then you need to implement `operator<<` for the `BasePayroll` class, and then you can dereference the `BasePayroll*` pointer when passing it to `std::cout`, eg: `std::cout << *(*it);`

Comment: You could apply the * operator again *(*it).  Note *address is the same as address[0] so you could also use that if you want to differentiate stuff a bit: (*it)[0].  Although you could also clean this up by ditching the iterator for some other for loop notations.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<BasePayroll*> emps; // when you dereference the iterator once you get
                                // what you have stored in the vector, a BasePayroll*
emps.push_back(&Jane);

for (std::vector<BasePayroll*>::iterator it = emps.begin(); it != emps.end(); it++ ) {
    std::cout << *(*it);        // do double dereferencing to get a BasePayroll& instead
}
```

You could also let a [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) do the first level of dereferencing:

```
for(BasePayroll* pbpr : emps) {
    std::cout << *pbpr;
}
```

For the obove to work you also need

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const BasePayroll& bpr) {
    // output BasePayroll-data using bpr
    return os;
}
```